# Margem ou Posicionamento do Link Âncora

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um link ancora que leva de um botão no topo para uma determinada parte da página, mas como o meu menu acompanha a página, acaba ficando cortado como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria pra dar um espaça? Margem ou posição, não sei, mas preciso que o link desça de forma que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando um script para suavisar a rolagem:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Coloca um + 20 depois do .top. 
`scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top + 20`

Comment: show @Zoom, funcionou perfeitamente, só coloquei valor negativo, pois o positivo subiu mais ainda, mas a solução foi perfeita! Obrigado!

Comment: Então era negativo mesmo. Sempre confundo... Rsrsrs

Comment: Olá. @Zoom insira a resposta para ficar respondido :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um - 20 depois do .top.

```
scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 20
```

Assim ele se posiciona -20 pixels do seu elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser chegar ao mesmo resultado usando somente CSS, é só adicionar o seguinte ao seu style.css ou custom.css

```css
:target:before {
content:"";
display:block;
height:90px; /* fixed header height*/
margin:-90px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

Onde o 90px é o espaçamento que vc deseja